# Creating progress bar without using "onprogress" event

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload, microsoft-edge

I've been working on an upload feature that uses HTML5 xhr.upload.progress listener to update the progress bar.  It works great everyone except for Edge, which, starting with version 15 has a bug in progress listener implementation.  It manifests itself in progress event been triggered once, when the upload is complete.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12224510/

I looked at a few upload frameworks (FineUpload, jQuery File Upload), but they all seem to rely on that feature, as well.  How was it done before progress listener existed?  I hope there are other options besides Flash, which I won't be able to use.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing they used `onreadystatechange`. There are intermediate states that are triggered during progress of the upload or download.

Comment: Not for progress, though.  readyState has loading and done, but that's about it.  I guess it was all Flash :(